# Manual two-way binding using AngularJS's ngModelController

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a working directive that creates a two-way binding between an ng-model and an array of checkbox objects. Usage:

```
<div hardware-ids-picker ng-model="dataflow.idTypes"></div>
```

Here is the two-way binding code in the directive, where `hardwareIds` are the checkboxes:

```
// model --> view
ngModel.$viewValue.forEach(function (id) {
    hardwareIds.forEach(function (hardwareId) {
        if (id === hardwareId.value) hardwareId.__checked = true;
    });
});

// view --> model
scope.$watch("hardwareIds", function (hardwareIds) {
    var hardwareIds = HardwareIdsService.bindIds(hardwareIds);
    ngModel.$setViewValue(hardwareIds);
}, true);
```

I've read [here](http://www.chroder.com/2014/02/01/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/) that the proper way to do this is with Angular's `$formatters` and `$parsers` service, so I tried pushing a formatting function into the `ngModel.$formatters` array:

```
function formatter(modelValue) {
    modelValue.forEach(function (id) {
        scope.hardwareIds.forEach(function (hardwareId) {
            if (id === hardwareId.value) hardwareId.__checked = true;
        });
    });

    return scope.hardwareIds;
}
ngModel.$formatters.push(formatter);
ngModel.$render();
```

I'm returning an array of objects which should be set as the `$viewValue`, and then using the `ngModel.$render()` function to display that in the DOM, but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong? Or is my original working solution acceptable?

Comment: A jsfiddle would help me tell you exactly how to fix it, but basically your `$render` is useless. That would be used inside of the formatter. Right now, you're just calling it one time at initiation, rather than calling it every time the UI needs to update.

Comment: I don't think formatter and parsers are really required in your scenario, they are used to transform the data, not to add checks. Do let me know if i am missing something

Comment: @Safi yeah, this all needs to be rethought. His first example has a $watch on `hardwareIds` and the second has the formatter applied to the model `dataflow.idTypes`. The model would have to be `hardwareIds` for the formatter to be applied like he wants, but that doesn't help him here.

Comment: @Safi you're right, formatters and parsers are appropriate for customizing 2-way binding on a single input, not a list of checkboxes.